# Single nodes after mpmetis partitioning

Tags: mesh-generation, partitioning

I was checking partitioning capabilities of Metis (mpmetis) when I noticed, that it leaves two single nodes. I have marked them in red 
[image]

Have you seen something similar or maybe it is my mistake?

The entire mesh
[image]

Elements are typical, 8-nodal quadrilaterals. I used mpmetis without any options to create 2 partitions. It produces two partitions, where the first part contains single nodes - not connected to any elements while the second partition is fine.

Partition 1:
[image]

Partition 2:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Metis does not guarantee that the partitions are non-empty, so your code must deal with this situation.

Comment: OK, but even if the code deals with it, the loadbalancing will still be horrible, no? Why does Metis produce this output?